# Temp Table Name

Tags: sql-server

Trying to understand the last 12 hex value that is part of the temptable. 
Every new temp table I create the value increment by 1. This tells me that the value should exist on a system table.

From the TempDB log, I can see SQL is inserting/updating following table

```
sys.sysschobjs
sys.syscolpars
sys.sysrowsets
sys.sysallocunits
sys.sysrscols
sys.sysidxstats
```

I analysed the data changes on the above tables, however, I am not able to locate the column.

Comment: Why? What's the issue?

Comment: What is it you're *actually* trying to achieve? If you're trying to get the "real" name of a temp table, this will do you little good, because SQL Server will refuse access to it under that name. If you want to know the algorithm SQL Server uses to generate these names, that will do you even *less* good, as it's subject to change without notice (and likely not even deterministic depending on actual server activity).

Comment: No issues. As I said I am trying to understand the internals of SQL.

Comment: Well, as you've observed, it's probably a simple counter of some sort, but as tempdb only exists while the server is running, it's not required to have physical presence, let alone one exposed in a system view. It could literally just be a `static volatile long` somewhere in memory maintained with an `InterlockedIncrement`. (I have no idea if this is actually the case; if you're really unreasonably curious I think hooking up a debugger is the only way to go.)